# Rspec concatenate expect statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

```
expect(a).not_to be(6).or expect(a).to eq(6).and expect(b).to eq(3)
```

This code is not executable.

But what I'm trying to test is this statement:

```
(a == 6 AND b == 3) OR a != 6
```

How do I concatenate the expect statements without the use of an `if` statement ?

Comment: `expect((a == 6 && b == 3) || a != 6).to be_truthy` ?

Comment: that was perfect, thanks